Bar chart on PowerBI
I have a dataset with the date column (month, year) and a value I keep measuring each month( which is SOH). Each row is a value for each month.
I created new columns for the month, year, and quarter.
I want to create a bar chart on PowerBI that uses the quarter and year to be the x axis and I want to display the value in the last month of that particular quarter as the y axis.
I tried creating columns and measures but none of them worked.

Add your sample data and your expected output.
